# Error in recapcha Phone Auth firebase with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha, google-play-integrity-api

I have a firebase integration and my application in flutter, I am using phone login so that I receive a code as an SMS. When I make the call and send my phone number, the following appears on my console:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXWFr.png)

I have already added my SHA1 and SHA56, both for debug and launch and the one provided by Google when you upload the app to the play store. I already added these fingerprints to my Firebase project, and to the Google Cloud API Key, I enabled the Integrity pi, and all the APIs that I use, such as Maps. I already downloaded the new google-serviles.json file and it still has the same error. The map and all map services are working correctly for me except this login:These are the enabled apis:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx6qB.png)

I also already have the tag: com.google.android.geo.API_KEY added to my manifest, with the value of my API Key. And these are my dependencies:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXcwt.png)

None of this worked for me, nor does the application that is published in the play store work

Comment: Are you testing on a real device? Also what is the version OS of your device?

It seems you did too many attempt. You should wait before trying again with the same phone number

Comment: Please don't share code/error as a image